# Ambiguous use of 'subscript' after converting to swift 2.3

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I got this Errors after I converting to swift 2.3.

```
guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                    throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
                }

                guard
                    let loadedWeather = json["weather"]![0]["description"] as? String,
                    let loadedTemperatur = json["main"]!["temp"] as? Float,
                    let loadedWindSpeed = json["wind"]!["speed"] as? Float
                    else {
                        print("Weather JSON-Parsing failed")
                        return
                }
```

The `Ambiguous use of subscript` error comes by declaring "loadedWeather, loadedTemperatur and loadedWindSpeed".

Already tried to change NSDictionary to Dictionary and other things, helped on another position in code, but here....

thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the issue is that the compiler cannot work out what `json["weather"]` is, You may need to be more specific in your code.

Try

```
let loadedWeather = (json["weather"] as! [[String:AnyObject]])[0]["description"] as? String
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Both of you solved my Problem, I decided for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because compiler doesn't know what are the intermediary object is in each of your line ... so may be

```
   if let weather = json["weather"] as? [[String:String]], firstObject = weather.first as? [String:String]{
        let loadedWeather = firstObject["description"]
   }

   // same for other objects i.e. `json["main"]` and `json["wind"]` with its return type
```