# how to solve "type Any has no subscript members" error?

Tags: ios, swift

I have written code in swift 2.3 while converting to swift 3 i am getting error like "type Any has no subscript members"

```
let userDetail:Any = (GJCommon.sharedInstance.getUserInfo() as? NSDictionary)!

    print(userDetail)

    let userImage = (userDetail["Vehicle"]["bike_photo"] as? String)!
```

In this line i am getting error "let userImage = (userDetail["Vehicle"]["bike_photo"] as? String)!" Please help to do this.

Comment: I can see at least 6 questions with the same title in the "Related" section on the right. Are you sure that none of them helps to solve your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466624/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-after-converting-to-swift-2-3/39466734#39466734

Comment: Yes here my error is getting values from dictionary. no one cleared my doubt.

Comment: what is the output of `GJCommon.sharedInstance.getUserInfo()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [type any? has no subscript members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956785/type-any-has-no-subscript-members)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if let userDetail = GJCommon.sharedInstance.getUserInfo() as? [String:AnyObject] {

    print(userDetail)

    let userImage = (userDetail["Vehicle"]["bike_photo"] as? String)!
}
```

Comment: let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks! its working if i am using NSDictionary insteadof [String:AnyObject]  what about     let userImage = (userDetail["Vehicle"]["bike_photo"] as? String)!

Comment: Is there any possible to do like this please edit your answer and write that possible also please.

Comment: `NSDictionary` instead of `[String:AnyObject] ` works?

Comment: getting same type any error in this line let userImage = (userDetail["Vehicle"]["bike_photo"] as? String)!

Comment: what is the output of `print GJCommon.sharedInstance.getUserInfo()?`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access userDetail as an NSDictionary but it is of type Any.

As #Mr.UB said (beat me to it), change the first line to:

```
let userDetail = (GJCommon.sharedInstance.getUserInfo() as? NSDictionary)!
```

And it should then compile, although other parts of your code may then object. More context would be useful.

However your use of ! to force unwrap this and a later result is a bad idea. Use conditional unwrapping to catch errors more gracefully and avoid an App that crashes regularly.